# What program to write pdf including other pdf on Linux from Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab, pypdf

On an Ubuntu server, I want to create pdfs which include other static pdfs. I have tried using ReportLab with pyPdf. Ideally I would use ReportLab to do the whole thing, but in order to import the pdfs requires their PageCatcher which has a large recurring fee.

So I use pyPdf to merge a page created with ReportLab and my other pdfs. The problem is that even though this looks fine in Acrobat and Foxit, part of one of the pages prints garbled on a Xerox 7400 color printer. I can't figure out the issue, but would be willing to buy a more integrated solution if it existed and was reasonably priced.  I thought PDF Creator Pilot was it until I saw that it was Windows only.

So is there a reasonably priced ($1K or less) solution or a different suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of success with the Java library [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/). They have a great library of samples for pretty much anything you could think of doing with PDF files. This example is for concatenating PDF files and sounds like it would do what you need: http://itextpdf.com/examples/index.php?page=example&id=123. There is also [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) which is another great Java based PDF manipulation library.

I realize that you are looking for a Python based solution but there may not be many other options. If you are using the Jython interpreter instead of CPython, integrating in iText should be trivial. If not, then you could consider calling out to it as a separate process. I realize that may not be idea for your situation but I figured I would mention it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-Python answer.  If you are just merging pages, then [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) does that well (along with a lot of other things).